# From multiple json files match the document's keywords with another external list of keywords. and return the files who have matched keywords?

Tags: json, machine-learning, nlp, dataset, data-science

I am a new learner of NLP.

1. I have a corpus of 40k Scientific papers in JSON format.
2. Each article (JSON files) has its own specific keywords. [document_keywords]
3. I, on the other hand,  have a list of desired keywords that I have prepared by myself to parse the specific genre articles. [my_desired_keywords]

If any of the ***document_keywords*** matches with ***my_desired_keywords*** then I only need those article names(JSON fine names)?

I would really appreciate it if you show me some lights with your experiences.
Thanks in advance.

Cheers,

Comment: If your question is about machine-learning, use tag [machine-learning]. [ml] for meta-language. Usage of appropriate tags might help get answer faster

Comment: This looks like a straightforward searching problem. Where does NLP or machine "learning"  come in?